# Excel VBA stops/step-into suddenly not working

Tags: excel, vba

My VBA stops have stopped working for some reason in the excel workbook that I am working in. (Stops still work in other workbooks.) No matter how simple my procedures are, I cannot F8 through or stop my code.

Do you have any thoughts as to why might be occurring?

Here is what I have tried so far:

Debug > Compile project

Verifying I have no strange references

Restarting my computer & excel

Exporting and then removing all modules, closing excel, then reimporting my modules

Comment: Please try: export  all modules, save as xlsx file, close workbok and excel, reopen workbook and import modules.

Comment: Several years ago, I had VBA act really weird (freeze, not step etc)... I tried what "taller" recommends (and certainly, try that first), but even that wouldn't work (As modules back then apparently carried some Other information with them that was corrupted). What Did work was copying the VBA TEXT ONLY, saving the workbook as xlsx, and then pasting it back into new modules identically named.

Comment: Thank you both for the tips. I gave up on it last night and I am not having that issue this morning. If I ever have that problem again, I will attempt to resolve by following both of your suggestions. Much appreciated!

Comment: It may just be coincidence but I had exactly the same problem last night in Excel 2021 with a toy VBA script that the debugger refused point blank to execute. It would only run the first line of any subroutine and then drop out no error. I could still edit and set breakpoints but could not single step, use F8 or do anything other than execute the very first line of each sub. I confirmed this by changing the first two lines of each to debug.print "NameofSub" and debug.print "second line". The problem was resolved by rebooting - after that the code worked again. It was trivial code.